# How to fix/restore mouse controls in tmux on iTerm2?

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I've been playing around with my iTerm2 shell setup. Previously I'd been able to use mouse controls to resize panes, etc. in tmux by simply adding `set -g mouse on` to `.tmux.conf`.

Now, however, it's just not working in iTerm2 (but it is working in the built-in Terminal app). I'm not sure what I did to mess things up. My best guess is that this line that I had used in `.tmux.conf` was the culprit.

```
set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

No idea what that syntax means (I copied/pasted from a SO answer). Even when I remove that line from `.tmux.conf`, the mouse mode still doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix/restore standard tmux-mouse-mode behavior in iTerm2?

Comment: I have used that line `set -g terminal-overrides 'xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'` in `.tmux.conf` to fix scrolling issues in MobaXTerm (a Windows SSH client)

Answer (score 34):

In my case, I must have somehow caused this "Enable Mouse Reporting" setting to get unchecked. Re-checking solved my problem.

[image]

Comment: fricking genius is what you are

Comment: In my case it was the sub-checkbox under that, "Report mouse wheel events"

Comment: thks, vim set mouse=a not work, can not drag window , this fix the problem

Comment: This worked for me as well!